# Is there any way to apply exception attribute to asp.net web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I am working on a webservice which has the following method below, I want to create an exception attribute so that I can inject that attribute on other functions in my webservices if required and log the error.

Here is the code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SwitchGetEmployeeLeaveBalances(string Str)
{
    LeaveModel objLeaveModel = ObjectDeserializer.Deserialize<LeaveModel>(Str);

    string requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objLeaveModel);

    DateTime? _requestSentTime = objLeaveModel.RequestTime;
    string res = "";

    try
    {
        // get current request received time
        _reqRecTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");
        AppMFSService.AppMFSServiceSoapClient mfs = new AppMFSService.AppMFSServiceSoapClient();
        res = mfs.AppGetEmployeeLeaveBalances(Str);

        List<Response> response = ObjectDeserializer.Deserialize<List<Response>>(res);
        _status = response.DefaultIfEmpty().First().Status;

        if (response.DefaultIfEmpty().First().Data != "")
            _result = response.DefaultIfEmpty().First().Data;
        else
            _result = response.DefaultIfEmpty().First().Status;

        _reqResTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _status = ex.ToString();
        _result = ex.ToString();
    }

    try
    {
        // creating routing transaction model
        rTrx = new RoutingTransaction(Convert.ToInt32(objLeaveModel.TerminalID), "001", "001", "", objLeaveModel.MobileNumber, objLeaveModel.AccountNo, "", _reqRecTime.ToString(), _requestSentTime.ToString(), _result, _reqResTime, _status, "0", "059", GetServiceAddress.getMfsAppAddress(), objLeaveModel.UserName, objLeaveModel.TellerName, requestString);

        // store routing transaction into switch routing transaction table
        client = new StoreSwitchRouting(rTrx);

        // calling transaction routing storing method
        client.store();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //_result = string.Join("*", new string[] { _result, "Storing into transaction table failed" });

        Logs.log(ex.ToString());
    }

    return res;
}
```

I tried creating a `global.asax.cs` file and adding logging logic on `Application_error` method, but that just puts the logging functionality on exception at the application level.